# Animate item-swap in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've implemented a recycler view with an adapter and everything. I can reverse the list of items with

```
Collections.reverse(items);
```

and then run through the list to notify the adapter of this change

```
final int end = items.size() - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(0, end - i);
}
```

So far so good. What I want to do now is to swap two items in that list and animate this change.

```
Collections.swap(items, 5, 8);

mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(5, 8);
mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(8, 5);
```

The problem is, this is not being animated and I couldn't find out why.

I do want something similar to the simple reverse animation.

Any ideas?

Comment: It gives to you some error on LogCat?

Comment: No error. The swapping just works without an animation. The ArrayList is reordered and I can see that on the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Soon after I wrote this I hacked a little more and found the reason. Turns out, my problem does relate to the following thread:

[No animation on item removal on RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187733/no-animation-on-item-removal-on-recyclerview)

I did mess up my notifyDataSetChanged() and notifyItemMoved(0, 1) calls. Once notifyDataSetChanged() is called, the items are swapped without an animation and notifyItemMoved has no effect.